# How do we access the previous versions of Google caches?

Tags: google-search

How do we access the "earlier caches" of Google?

For example, the website http://www.onemillionpeople.com/ is current down for maintenance.

When I access the Google's web cache, it still shows "down for maintenance": http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:C1MBVt7fGTEJ:www.onemillionpeople.com/+one+million+people&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

How do we access the *previous* versions of that cache?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if you can access the previous version of a Google cache, but Internet Wayback Machine is your friend.

The following page shows the snapshots of that page in the past. There are 3 snapshots in 2011, latest on May, 3rd.

http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://onemillionpeople.com

Comment: that's cool bro =D

Comment: @Sathya: The link does not work that way (I made it that way when I first wrote my answer, but since clicking fails, I changed it). I'm rolling back. BTW, I'm on Firefox.

Comment: huh, go figure, doesn't work here either, my apologies - I should've checked before editing.

Comment: @Sathya: No problem. I think it fails because of the asterisk somehow...

Comment: Yeah, the asterisk gets URL-encoded during the Markdown-to-HTML conversion, but the wayback machine doesn't seem to URL-decode it

Comment: There might be another thing to it, if you want a website to be mirrored or have copies, you need to submit its URL. It works as inded right now.

Comment: It must be said however that Google crawls and caches many more webpages than archive unfortunately.